# Hyperbolic Cosine and Sine in Terms of 3-D Velocity

Tags: special-relativity

Intuitively, why are  $\cosh(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$ and $\sinh(\theta) = \frac{v/c}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$ true in special relativity?

Is there some picture I can draw in Minkowski space (or anywhere)

[image]

to derive these or to show that they are obvious? (Analogous to using the Pythagorean theorem to derive $\cos(\theta) = \frac{adj}{hyp}$)

My derivation of the Lorentz transformations follows Landau in motivating the hyperbolic form of these equations, but the derivations of the above equalities in Landau are algebraic and I hope  there is a more geometric way to see these as obvious, perhaps using the area interpretation of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ (as giving the area of a hyperbolic sector or something, though I don't see how to relate this to velocity).

Comment: I think the only 'motivation' of geometric nature is studing the minkowsky quadratic form induced by diag(1,-1,-1,-1) . In 1D, it reduces to diag(1,-1), and the only way to preserve this form is by something like hyperbolic rotations. I don't know if you call this geometric or algebraic, but I don't think that you are going to find anything like $cos(\theta)=adj/hyp$